# Rails mass updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the console and I have a model called `line` with a `fontsize` field.

I want to normalise my font sizes so that fonts between 20-25 are set to 24 and any above are set to 28 and any fonts in the 30s is set to 32.

How do I go about mass updating my database from the console like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm reading this as something you only want to do once, so I've gone for readability over performance or brevity)

Assuming Rails >3 and that your model is called `Line` (with a capital "L"), the following should do you:

```
Line.where(:fontsize => (20..25).each {|x| x.update_attribute :fontsize, 24)
Line.where(:fontsize => (26..29).each {|x| x.update_attribute :fontsize, 28)
Line.where(:fontsize => (30..39).each {|x| x.update_attribute :fontsize, 32)
```

Comment: There is better way doing the same, but faster:
`Line.update_all({:fontsize => 24},{:fontsize => (20..25)} )` and etc.
See [http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

Comment: @MarkGuk's solution will definitely be faster, but won't run callbacks or validations; this may or may not be something you want...

Comment: Validations **not** get runned on `update_attribute` [http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute)